# Estimated impact popup behind navbar

Tags: bug

I noticed today the "people reached popup" was behind the navbar. I changed (increased) the `z-index` on the tooltip which solved the problem, so this shouldn't be much of an issue.

[image: Popup behind navbar]

Comment: @Floern Ah, tried to find it but guess I did not search far enough :) thanks!

Comment: @Floern Ah that post is from May, so I'm not sure if I should delete/close this one.

Comment: I think it's still the same issue, it's never been fixed.

Comment: Allow for 6 to 8 weeks to have all z-index values to be re-ordered ...

Comment: A ok :) Consider it closed